# Color text to EditText

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext

I'm having difficulty in putting the text color of a EditText chosen from ColorPicker. how should I do?

```
private void cColor(int color) {
    int rgb = Color.red(color) + Color.blue(color) + Color.green(color);
    mCat.setTextColor();

}
```

Comment: Hmmm... that makes little sense. Why are you not calling `setTextColor(color)`  directly?

Answer (score 1):

Just do :-

```
editText.setTextColor(Color.RED + Color.BLUE);
```

or if you have  colour codes defined in strings.xml or colors.xml, Do this :-

```
    editText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red)+ getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```

strings.xml

```
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but if you want to get the color based on RGB parts try this:

```
private void cColor(int red, int green, int blue) {

    int rgb = Color.rgb(red, green, blue)

    mCat.setTextColor(rgb);
}
```